# Marking an unowned type as deprecated or obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'd like to create a custom version of `TimeoutException` (I'll only override the constructor to add some more information) and I'd want to prevent / discourage future creations (calls to the constructor) of the `System.TimeoutException` for a specific module. Is it possible to mark the constructor of `TimeoutException` as deprecated / obsolete to do so?

The same goes for the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsTrue(System.Boolean),` I'd like to deprecate/obsolete this method (only the implementation that takes only the `Boolean`, I don't want to touch the ones that take `(Boolean, String)` or `(Boolean, String, Object[]).`

I know there are `[Obsolete] [Deprecate]` to do this, but, since the methods are not declared / implemented in the project I don't know how to add them.

Comment: Your engineers were so preoccupied with whether or not the COULD, that they never stopped think if they SHOULD.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a code style tool with a custom rule.

Comment: You should be able to use FxCop and create a custom rule that looks for a call to the constructor you don't want to use.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, you can't override a constructor

Comment: Was looking for multiple options, FxCop being one of them.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic not pedantic, you are right. I'll inherit from TimeoutException and I'll have a constructor which calls its super adding some other info, that's not overriding (used the wronged term).

Comment: You could possibly do something with Mono.Cecil or PostSharp to weave in a custom aspect around it to throw runtime exceptions, but does this actually help? I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't mark code in somebody else's binary as deprecated or obsolete.

As commenters mentioned, you could write a custom FxCop rule to catch this.  Better yet, if you are using the latest Visual Studio, write a custom Roslyn analyzer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx).

Personally, I would just rely on the team having a good code review process and poking developers with pointy sticks when they use the wrong thing.

Comment: I feel like even if there's voodoo that allows you to inject these attributes into an unowned type it would be at runtime. Having these at runtime likely  defeats the entire purpose, as they likely couldn't trigger a runtime exception.